# Problem error msg "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing , or the punctuation is incorrect"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

My problem is: I get an error that appears in my code every time I run it and I don't know why; please I need your help.

When I run the query, it worked but when I tried to code it, I get an error

> A Runsql action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement

This is my code:

```
Sub Import_Cable_list()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL =" SELECT SPI_query.Loop_name, Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM, Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_FROM, Panel_from_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Panel_FROM, PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_TO, PANEL_TO_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_TO, PANEL_TO_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Panel_TO, Cable_List_ITR.CABLE_NUM, Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cable_Number, Cable_List_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Cable_Number, Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_TO AS Cabinet, PANEL_TO_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cabinet, PANEL_TO_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_state_Cabinet" & _
     " FROM SPI_query INNER JOIN (PANEL_TO_ITR INNER JOIN (Jb_Cabinet INNER JOIN (Panel_from_ITR INNER JOIN Cable_List_ITR ON Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Cable_List_ITR.PANEL_FROM) ON Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_FROM = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM) ON PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM) ON SPI_query.Clean_Tag_Number = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM;"


DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT SPI_query.Loop_name, Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM, Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_FROM, Cable_List_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Panel_FROM, PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_TO, PANEL_TO_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_TO, PANEL_TO_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Panel_TO, Cable_List_ITR.CABLE_NUM, Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cable_Number, Cable_List_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Cable_Number, Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_TO AS Cabinet, Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cabinet, Cable_List_ITR.[ITR State] AS ITR_State_Cabinet " & _
         "FROM SPI_query INNER JOIN (((PANEL_TO_ITR INNER JOIN Panel_from_ITR ON PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM) INNER JOIN Cable_List_ITR ON Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Cable_List_ITR.PANEL_FROM) INNER JOIN Jb_Cabinet ON Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_FROM) ON SPI_query.Clean_Tag_Number = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM ; "
```

Comment: i did what u told me and now i have an other error message  that appears " A Runsql action requirs an argument consisting of an SQL statement "

Comment: It is a _select_ query. Those you don't "run", but _open_.

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: I modified my code as u see in my question , i edited but i still have the same problem

Comment: Yes. If you wish to _run_ a query, it must be an action query (insert, update, create), not a select query.

Comment: i don't wont to run a query , i am trying to generate a table in access

Comment: i am a begginer in  access please if u can explain more and thank u

Comment: Then use an [insert-into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) or a [select-into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) query.

Comment: OK. Then study that link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query

```
strSQL = "SELECT SPI_query.Loop_name,
 Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM,
 Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_FROM,
 `Cable_List_ITR.ITR State` AS ITR_State_Panel_FROM,
 PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_TO,
 PANEL_TO_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Panel_TO,
 `PANEL_TO_ITR.ITR State` AS ITR_State_Panel_TO,
 Cable_List_ITR.CABLE_NUM,
 Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cable_Number,
 `Cable_List_ITR.ITR State` AS ITR_State_Cable_Number,
 Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_TO AS Cabinet,
 Cable_List_ITR.ITR AS ITR_Cabinet,
 `Cable_List_ITR.ITR State` AS ITR_State_Cabinet" & _
         "FROM SPI_query 
         INNER JOIN (
             (
                 (PANEL_TO_ITR INNER JOIN Panel_from_ITR ON PANEL_TO_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM) 
                INNER JOIN Cable_List_ITR ON Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Cable_List_ITR.PANEL_FROM
            ) 
        INNER JOIN Jb_Cabinet ON Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM = Jb_Cabinet.PANEL_FROM
        ) 
        ON SPI_query.Clean_Tag_Number = Panel_from_ITR.PANEL_FROM ; "
```

Comment: Please indicate how this helps solve the original question. As it stands, the existing error will still occur as there is no space where needed (` AS ITR_State_CabinetFROM SPI_query` should read ` AS ITR_State_Cabinet FROM SPI_query`).